# Average of elements in a 2d list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like the following:

```
[[1, 1], [7, 7], [20, 20], [9, 9], [-12, -12]]
```

And I'm trying to have a new list which has the same number of lists inside, but changes the value of the elements by calculating the average of an element with the element after and before.
What do I mean by that ?:
Let's say I have the sub-list sub = [7,7]
at index 1. I want this list to be [9,9], because sub[1][0] + lst_before_sub[0][0] + lst_after_sub[1][0] = 7 + 1 + 20 = 28, and 28//3 = 9 (I want integer divison).

The ideal output would be:

```
[[4, 4], [9, 9], [12, 12], [5, 5], [-1, -1]]
```

I have currently this code:

```
copy_l = copy.deepcopy(audio_data)
sub_list = []
for i in range(0, len(audio_data)-1):
    sub_data = []
    for j in range(2):
        if i == 0:
            audio_data[i][j] += int(audio_data[i+1][j] / 2)
            sub_data.append(audio_data[i][j])
        elif audio_data[i+1] == audio_data[-1]:
            audio_data[i+1][j] = int((audio_data[i+1][j]+audio_data[i][j])/2)
            sub_data.append(audio_data[i+1][j])
        else:
            audio_data = copy_l
            audio_data[i][j] = int((audio_data[i-1][j] + audio_data[i][j] + audio_data[i+1][j])/3)
            sub_data.append(audio_data[i][j])
    sub_list.append(sub_data)
print(sub_list)
```

where audio_data is the list [[1, 1], [7, 7], [20, 20], [9, 9], [-12, -12]] that I passed in.

(I have separated the average calculation in three cases:
- First element of the list: [1,1] so the average is just 1 + 7 // 2 (no element before [1,1])
- Last element of the list: [-12,-12] so the average is just -12 + 9 // 2 (no element after [-12,-12])
- All the elements in between
)

Problem is, my output (sub_list) is: 
`[[4, 4], [9, 9], [12, 12], [-1, -1]]`
And it seems that [9,9] never turns into [5,5]
Does someone have any idea how to achieve what I want, or even an idea to make it simpler ? I hope I was clear enough, if not feel free to ask me more details, thank you!

**EDIT:**
I'm seeking a solution without numpy, list comprehension or zip.

Comment: Note that the last element could be `-1` or `-2`, depending on your definition of integer division. The definition you describe: `(-12 + 9) // 2` would be equal to `-2`, whereas the calculation in your code: `int((-12 + 9) / 2)` gives `-1`.

Comment: You're right, what I want is int(expression)

Comment: What is wrong with list comprehension and `zip()`?

Comment: I just can't use it, I have some instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
data = [[1, 1], [7, 7], [20, 20], [9, 9], [-12, -12]] 

out = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    first =  max(i -1, 0)  # don't have the start of the slice <0
    last = min(i + 2, len(data))  # neither beyond the end of the list
    mean = [sum(col) // (last-first) for col in zip(*data[first:last])]
    out.append(mean)

print(out)

# [[4, 4], [9, 9], [12, 12], [5, 5], [-2, -2]]
```

We take slices of data around the current item.

Then, we `zip` the sublists, and we calculate the result on the first (resp. second) values of the sublists.

Also, note that using Python's integer division, we get -2 for `-3//2`, not -1 as you got by rounding to the closest to 0. If you really want to do that, you'll have to use a custom function for the division.

Comment: `last = i + 2` should be `last = i + (2 if i == len(data)-1 else 1)`  as currently you're dividing the final sum by `3` instead of by `2`. Your result is accidentally consistent with the desired output (as `-3//3 == -1` but `-3//2 == -2` and `int(-3/2) == -1`) but it would fail for most other lists.

Comment: Yep! Too bad I got lucky and didn't notice... Thanks!

Comment: The `-1` version of the result can be achieved by simple float division with truncation: `int(sum(col) / (last-first))` (on the off-chance that it matters to the OP)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the solution, I should have mention that I can't use neither zip nor list comprehension! Do you think you could "translate" your code into something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NumPy solution:

```py
import numpy as np

def mean3(data):
    return np.convolve(np.r_[data[:2].mean(), data, data[-2:].mean()], np.ones(3), 'valid')//3
```

```py
>>> np.apply_along_axis(mean3, 0, audio_data)
array([[ 4.,  4.],
       [ 9.,  9.],
       [12., 12.],
       [ 5.,  5.],
       [-2., -2.]])
```

Or, if you prefer the `int(x/y)` definition of integer division:

```py
import numpy as np

def mean3(data):
   return (np.convolve(np.r_[data[:2].mean(), data, data[-2:].mean()], np.ones(3), 'valid')/3).astype(int)
```

```py
>>> np.apply_along_axis(mean3, 0, audio_data)
array([[ 4,  4],
       [ 9,  9],
       [12, 12],
       [ 5,  5],
       [-1, -1]])
```